# Consulta Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT termocuplas.id_modulo, transmisores.id_modulo
FROM termocuplas
INNER JOIN transmisores
ON termocuplas.id_caldera = transmisores.id_caldera
WHERE termocuplas.id_modulo = '3H'
```

La estoy ejecutando desde `localhost`, usando firefox mozilla, mi duda es por que al ejecutarla se queda en "Esperando a localhost" y al rato muestra este error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: (HY000/1105): Unknown error in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin2.10.1\libraries\dbi\mysqli.dbi.lib.php on line 181
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin2.10.1\libraries\dbi\mysqli.dbi.lib.php on line 181

Estoy usando `Wampserver`.

La tabla esta estructurada de la siguiente forma:

```
tabla termoscuplas:
    id_modulo   varchar(4) 
    descripcion     varchar(100)
    vin0    varchar(7) 
    vin1    varchar(7) 
    vin2    varchar(7)  
    vin3    varchar(7)
    vin4    varchar(7)  
    vin5    varchar(7) 
    vin6    varchar(7)  
    vin7    varchar(7) 
    fecha   date 
    hora    time    
    id_caldera  varchar(2)
```

La `tabla termoscupla` tiene al rededor de 401,474 registros.

```
Tabla Transmisores:
    id_modulo   varchar(4) 
    descripcion     varchar(100)
    vin0    varchar(7) 
    vin1    varchar(7) 
    vin2    varchar(7)  
    vin3    varchar(7)
    vin4    varchar(7)  
    vin5    varchar(7) 
    vin6    varchar(7)  
    vin7    varchar(7) 
    fecha   date 
    hora    time    
    id_caldera  varchar(2)
```

La `tabla transmisores` tiene al rededor de 401,521 registros.

Ambos pesan al rededor de 107.2 MB... no se si es por que el tamaño de cada uno... de la cual se esta pegando,.... mi pc es una intel i3 con 4 gb de ram.

Answer (score 0):

El error que ves es porque la consulta le ha llevado más tiempo del esperado, y eso se puede solucionar de dos maneras:

- Reescribiendo la consulta para que sea más eficiente (pero no puedo hacerlo porque no estás mostrando detalles de tus tablas ni su contenido)
- Ampliando el tiempo máximo de ejecución (o incluso eliminándolo)

Para modificar el tiempo máximo de ejecución tendrás que modificar tus archivos de configuración de PHP como se muestra en el siguiente [link](http://biolucas.com/como-solucionar-el-error-maximum-execution-time-300-seconds-importar-archivos-phpmyadmin/)

En resumen lo que aconseja es

> editar el archivo `config.inc.php` que está en la carpeta `phpmyadmin/` y
>   añadirle al final (pero antes del símbolo `?>`) lo siguiente:
>
> `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;`
>
> Con esto ya está hasta 6000 segundos ( ... )
>
> También hay que modificar el `php.ini` cambiando los valores por los
>   siguientes:
>
> `max_execution_time = 5000`
>   `max_input_time = 5000`

Si éstos valores siguen dándote error podrías intentar eliminar el límite de tiempo usando el valor `0`, pero con mucho cuidado porque eso hará que se ejecute, potencialmente, por siempre, si es que hubiera algún problema en tus tablas.

Comment: Saludos!! ya aplique el cambio, la consulta esta tardando, segun estoy creyendo, tarda por que son muchos registros,,, aunque no me convence, ya que no se trata de la base  de datos de google..... la tabla esta estructurada como lo voy a añadir en la edicion de arriba, ya que por este mensaje no me deja transcribirlo de forma original.... espero logres ver el mensaje.

Comment: En lo que agregaste sigo sin saber qué campos son clave primaria, foránea, índices ... ejecuta `SHOW CREATE TABLE termoscuplas;` y `SHOW CREATE TABLE Transmisores;` para ver bien la estructura.

Comment: No le tengo clave primaria a ninguna de las tablas,, solo las tengo asi como te las mostre....

Comment: por cierto..... al modificar los archivos que me indicastes, la consulta se hace, pero tarda al rededor de 20 minutos para realizarla....

Comment: justo eso es lo que hace que demore tanto. deberías, por lo menos, hacer que `termocuplas.id_caldera` sea clave primaria y que `transmisores.id_caldera` sea una clave foránea referenciando a `termocuplas.id_caldera`

Comment: ... pero hay que ver si de verdad pueden ser clave primaria / foránea. Para asistirte mejor en eso sería bueno que formularas otra pregunta sólo con eso para no seguir escribiendo en los comentarios, puesto que tu consulta original fue resuelta (la consulta daba error y ya no da error) y que los detalles para agregar esas claves sería mejor dártelos con más comodidad

Comment: ok mil gracias!!! voy a modificarlo haber y te comento

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea por la consulta que se queda pensando, ya que no das mas informacion de tus tablas supongo que podrias tratar algo asi

```
SELECT * FROM termocuplas
    INNER JOIN transmisores
    ON termocuplas.PK=transmisores.PK
    WHERE termocuplas.id_modulo='algo';
```